# Regular Expressions for finding files

Tags: regex, r

Ok I'm giving up and ask the question after I read through the help article of regex and still don't have a clue what I'm looking for:

I Have a list of files:

```
files <- c("files_combined.csv","file_1-10.csv","file_11-20.csv",
           "file_21-30.csv","file_2731-2740.csv","file_2731-2740.txt")
```

I want only the csv files that start with `"file_"` and end with `".csv"`. I know the it looks something like this:

```
grep(pattern = "^file_???.csv$" ,files)
```

But I need to find the correct regular expression that ignores the number of characters between the first and the second pattern (`"file_"` + `".csv"`). I'd really appreciate if somebody knows a complete list with the regular expressions in R since it is tedious to read through the help every time and, as in my case not successful, sometimes...

Comment: Something like `"^file_.*\\.csv$"` maybe?

Comment: Does `grep("^file_.+\\.csv$",files,value=T)` do what you want?

Comment: For future reference, I have [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:QYGR8eBzzHsJ:www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) regex cheatsheet printed out and pasted on my office wall (site seem to be down for now, there are other versions I'm sure). I know regex seems intimidating at first... and the R docs are notoriously unedifying (still waiting on news about SO dox...). Perhaps you should also try poking around in some R regex questions, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%5Bregex%5D+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Regex are something that isn't R-specific - they exist on their own. That's why you won't learn to use them by reading the R doc page `?regex`. I'd suggest this tutorial to start: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

Comment: There is a side called ["txt2re"](http://www.txt2re.com/) which can create a regex pattern from a given String. Maybe this can help you in the future!

Comment: @MichaelChirico There's a pdf version of that cheatsheet accessible through the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20111024203537/http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/pdf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot! Seems David Arenburg and Heroka, you came up with the solution at the same time. Also thanks to MichaelChirico for providing the cheatsheet.

This is the answer to my specific problem:

```
grep("^file_.+\\.csv$",files,ignore.case = T)
```

As for problems with regex, this is helpful as well [txt2re](http://www.txt2re.com/)

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Heroka, you gave the answer but I cannot accept it as you posted it as a comment. I would like to close this...

Comment: @Idos The answer has been improved and now answers the question.

Comment: @JonGrub I don't really mind, it would be literallly the same answer as this. Close it by accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

R offers a function for doing wildcard expansion using glob patterns for those who don't like regex:

```
files <- Sys.glob("file_*.csv")
```

This should match your pattern.

Comment: That was my first guess as well. But it seems R has a different logic here. It's not working for me at least...

Comment: Well the documentation confirms that all systems should interpret '*' as "match zero or more characters", so it should match anything starting with "file_" and ending in ".csv", as required (files in current working directory).

Comment: So this is what happens: 
`> files <-c("files_combined.csv","file_1-10.csv","file_11-20.csv",
+ "file_21-30.csv","file_2731-2740.csv","file_2731-2740.txt")
> files <- Sys.glob("file_*.csv")
> files
character(0) `
compared to the other answer
`> grep("^file_.+\\.csv$",files,ignore.case = T)
[1] 2 3 4 5`

Comment: Okay, possibly stupid question here. Do you actually *have* such files in your current working directory? Your first line creates a character vector; your second line (the Sys.glob one) actually looks in your current working directory for files that match that pattern. Does list.files() return a vector that includes the desired files?

Comment: I see now where my mistake was. The combination of `"file_*.csv"` does not work with `grep` or `list.files`. That's why I couldn't replicate it on my example character vector. But you are 100% right when it comes to finding the actual files I was looking for (which fit the pattern `"mesa_*.csv" ` the other one was just the example...)! It seems that `Sys.glob` uses wildcards while the other functions in R employ regular expressions (I wasn't aware of the [difference](http://www.cleo.com/support/byproduct/Lexicom/Usersguide/using_wildcards_and_regular_expressions.htm) so far).

Comment: I'd realised I'd rather jumped in with the assumption that you were looking for files, rather than wanting to work from a character vector (of files, perhaps as input from another function). As I'm used to Linux, I naturally think in terms of "ls \*.csv" or "ls file_\*.csv" and Sys.glob() is the natural function to use for that functionality. Yes, if you have a character vector as input then you'd need to use one of the regexp functions. Also, note that if you want/need to use regexp for finding files then list.files() takes a regexp pattern argument.